# Ansible replace multiple lines from variable

Tags: ansible

I have the following Ansible variable:

```
test_entries:
    "
    test-auth-ip=192.168.1.22
    test-auth-serv=example1.com
    test-auth-net=192.168.1.254
    test-auth-blabla=test123 
    "
```

I also have a text file which contains the following lines:

```
   test-auth-str1=null
   test-auth-str2=null
   test-auth-serv=null
   test-auth-net=0.0.0.0
   test-auth-str3=null
   test-auth-str4=null
```

I would like to be able to replace any line from the file which matches line from the variable until the "=" sign. (regex: ^test-auth(.*?=))

I read the Ansible doc. for "lineinfile" and "replace" functionalities. However, 
I couldn't find how to match line by line with regex.

**Expected result**

```
 test-auth-str1=null
 test-auth-str2=null
 test-auth-serv=example1.com
 test-auth-net=192.168.1.254
 test-auth-str3=null
 test-auth-str4=null
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to replace. Can you add a section with the expected output?

Comment: Split original string into lines (tokens), loop over them to call `replace` module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
test_entries:
 test-auth-ip     : 192.168.1.22
 test-auth-serv   : example1.com
 test-auth-net    : 192.168.1.254
 test-auth-blabla : test123
```

then in your task -

```
- replace:
    path: /your/file
    regexp: '^{{ item.key }}=.*$'
    replace: '{{ item.key }}={{ item.value }}'
  with_dict: "{{ test_entries }}"
```

I also often use an array of anonymous dictionaries, and whatever I named the attributes instead of `key` and `value`. The major differences are that it lets you control order (which doesn't seem to matter here) and skip the `key` & `value` keywords.